# Create a .eml (email) file in Java

Tags: java, email, outlook, eml

Anybody knows how to do this? I got all the information of the email (body, subject, from , to, cc, bcc) and need to generate an .eml file out of it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can construct [`javax.mail.Message`](https://javaee-spec.java.net/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html) object (or have it already constructed from the mail server) and then you can use [`writeTo()`](https://javaee-spec.java.net/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#writeTo%28java.io.OutputStream%29) method to save it to file.
See [JavaMail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) for more information.

Comment: ... package javax.mail does not exist

Comment: @Supuhstar - Old thread but for anyone else reading this, this relies on the javamail API.

Answer (score 27):

You can create eml files with the following code. It works fine with thunderbird and probably with other email clients:

```
public static void createMessage(String to, String from, String subject, String body, List<File> attachments) {
    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(Session.getInstance(System.getProperties()));
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        // create the message part 
        MimeBodyPart content = new MimeBodyPart();
        // fill message
        content.setText(body);
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(content);
        // add attachments
        for(File file : attachments) {
            MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
            attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            attachment.setFileName(file.getName());
            multipart.addBodyPart(attachment);
        }
        // integration
        message.setContent(multipart);
        // store file
        message.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(new File("c:/mail.eml")));
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Mailkit.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Mailkit.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: To save an html message, add `content.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");`

Answer (score 9):

EML files are just plain text files. The headers are separated from the body by a blank line. Headers look like this:

```
From: "DR CLEMENT OKON" <drclement@nigerianspam.com>
To: "You" <you@yourdomain.com>
Subject: REQUEST FOR URGENT BUSINESS RELATIONSHIP 
Date: Tue, 30 Sep 2008 09:42:47 -0400
```

For more info, the official spec is [RFC 2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html). It's actually not as hard to read as some RFCs.

Edit: When I said "plain text" I should have thought for a second. I really meant plain ASCII - and not the 8-bit "extended ASCII" either - just up to character 127. If you want more than seven bits, you need some kind of encoding and things get complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at a typical EML file it looks like a raw dump of the text communication that went to the server. So it is a text file containing the mail headers and body. To get your attachments, different views, etc in the correct format inside the EML file you need to MIME-encode the body and its parts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add HTML Stuff you have to add

```
content.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
```

(as Marco Sulla said) but also change

```
message.setContent(multipart);
```

to

```
message.setContent(multipart,"text/html");
```