# Create an email object in java and save it to file

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, pst, eml

i need to backup the emails contained in a PST file (outlook storage).
i'm using libpst which is the only free library i found on the web
( http://code.google.com/p/java-libpst/ )

so i can access all the information in each single email
(subject, body, sender ecc..), but i need to put them on a file

here someone said you can create an EML file from a "javax.mail.Message" object:
[Create a .eml (email) file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157195/create-an-eml-e-mail-file-in-java)

the problem is: how do i create this Message object?
i don't have a server or an email session, just the information contained in the email

p.s.
creating a .msg file would be fine too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You create a Message object the same way you would create one for sending,
but instead of sending it you write it to a file.  You don't need an email
server.  There's lots of examples of creating messages in the demo programs
included with the [JavaMail download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-138643.html), and in the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html).  See the
[Message.writeTo method](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/Part.html#writeTo%28java.io.OutputStream%29) to write the message to a file (Message is a Part,
and writeTo is on Part).

Answer (score 13):

Here's the code to create a valid eml file with java mail api. works fine with thunderbird and probably other email clients:

```
public static void createMessage(String to, String from, String subject, String body, List<File> attachments) {
    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(Session.getInstance(System.getProperties()));
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        // create the message part 
        MimeBodyPart content = new MimeBodyPart();
        // fill message
        content.setText(body);
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(content);
        // add attachments
        for(File file : attachments) {
            MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
            attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            attachment.setFileName(file.getName());
            multipart.addBodyPart(attachment);
        }
        // integration
        message.setContent(multipart);
        // store file
        message.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(new File("c:/mail.eml")));
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Mailkit.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Mailkit.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't any of you java answerers ever include the `import`s?

Comment: There are any way to remove the Message-ID generated?

Answer (score 0):

You can use mimeMessageHelper to create the message , as given below:

```
    import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
    
    public methodTocreateMessageObject(){
    MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    
    MimeMessageHelper mh= new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
    mh.setSubject(subject);
    mh.setTo(toArray(to));
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(cc)) {
    mh.setCc(toArray(cc));
    }
    mh.setFrom(from);
    
    mh.setText(body, true);
    
            if (attachmentFilenames != null) {
                for (String filename : attachmentFilenames) {
                    FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(filename);
                    mh.addAttachment(file.getFilename(), file);
                }
            }
    
            if (inlineAttachments != null && contentType!=null) {
                for (Entry<String, byte[]> inlineAttach : inlineAttachments.entrySet()) {
    
                    String cId = inlineAttach.getKey();
                    byte[] attachInByteStream = inlineAttach.getValue();
                    InputStreamSource attachSource = new ByteArrayResource(attachInByteStream);
                    mh.addInline(cId, attachSource, contentType);
    
                }
            }
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        message.writeTo(output);

        Date lastUpdatetime = new Date();

        try(OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("D:/mail2.eml")) {
            output.writeTo(outputStream);
        }
    }
```