# Is there any configuration SMTP like SpecifiedPickupDirectory in Java Mail?

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

In .NET we can configure output folder email instead of sending them like this.

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
      <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="c:\Temp\mail\"/>
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Is it possible to configure output folder for email like SpecifiedPickupDirectory in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void createMessage(String to, String from, String subject, String body, List<File> attachments) {
    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(Session.getInstance(System.getProperties()));
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        // create the message part 
        MimeBodyPart content = new MimeBodyPart();
        // fill message
        content.setText(body);
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(content);
        // add attachments
        for(File file : attachments) {
            MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
            attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            attachment.setFileName(file.getName());
            multipart.addBodyPart(attachment);
        }
        // integration
        message.setContent(multipart);
        // store file
        message.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(new File("c:/mail.eml")));
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Mailkit.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Mailkit.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

The solution base on this link
[Create an email object in java and save it to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167583/create-an-email-object-in-java-and-save-it-to-file)

Answer (score 1):

No.

You could use JavaMail to save the files into a folder instead of sending them, e.g., by using the Message.writeTo method.

Or you could write a JavaMail Transport provider that saved the files into a folder instead of sending them.

But there's nothing built in to JavaMail that just does this.

Comment: Do you have any samples?

Comment: Samples of what, exactly?  What did you try yourself?