# Open an eml file with java in linux

Tags: java, linux, desktop, eml

I am trying to open my created .eml file with java in linux. Currently I am using the following command:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(emlFile);
```

I create the eml file as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13136614/1754625) example.
This works for my windows system, but an error occurs in linux ubuntu 12.04.

EDIT: error message:

```
(process:19386): gnome-vfs-modules-WARNING **: Could not initialize inotify

java.io.IOException: Failed to show URI:file:/home/usr/workspace/programm/eml/mail.eml
at sun.awt.X11.XDesktopPeer.launch(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.X11.XDesktopPeer.open(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Desktop.open(Unknown Source)
```

I am happy for any help!

Comment: What error? Give more details please.

Comment: added my error message @Gigi

Comment: Put a breakpoint after you create the eml file, and see if it's at the location you expect. It may be that the file isn't being found.

Comment: The eml file is created correctly. ignis posted allready something helpful I stick to that atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs [java.awt.Desktop.open(File)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29)

> Throws IOException - if the specified file has no associated
>   application or the associated application fails to be launched

Comment: Thanks for your advice @ignis . As it seems linux didnt know how to open a .eml file. After I opened it with gedit and thunderbird, the error disapears. At the moment my java application opens the eml file with gedit and over my folder system it's opened with thunderbird.

Comment: This error still appears: (process:19950): gnome-vfs-modules-WARNING **: Could not initialize inotify

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. You should be able to open the file nevertheless.

Comment: Yes you are right @ignis, but it would be better if the java application would open that file with an e-mail client and not with the gedit.